# Article Table of Content as a sticky navigation

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, plugin, articles, content

I'm looking for a way (plugin, module?) to achieve the following:

- auto-generate a Table of Content for certain long Joomla articles based on HTML tags (H1,H2 etc.) or CSS classes of headings
- show the ToC as a sticky sidebar
- when scrolling through the content, highlight the current heading in the ToC (and optionally expand subheadings)

I have seen similar things on several websites, so I'm surprised I couldn't find any working solution for Joomla (or maybe I just didn't know what to search for).

I thought [JU ToC plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ju-toc/) should do something like this, but I can't get it to work. It generates a .jutoc element, but doesn't insert any links.

The [Uber TOC module](http://www.ubertoc.boomstrap.com/) seems to do exactly what I would like in its demo page, but its download is no longer available.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a similar plugin for a customer, but it was somewhat tailored to a specific site- At some point I would like to rework it to make it more universal so it can work for any website. You can see the plugin in action [here](http://www.solar-nation.org/alaska).

I didn't know that there were already some similar solutions (the extensions you mentioned on your question).

Following the links, I also found this in JED:

- https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/articles-toc/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/article-elements/extra-toc/

Also, just wanted to remind you that Joomla has already in its core the pagebreak plugin, that allows you to create table of content and split 1 article into many pages/step-pages.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Yes, the Extra TOC seems to do part of the job, though it doesn't highlight the current item.
I know the pagebreak plugin, but I don't want to split the article into more pages. I like the possibility to either scroll and read through the article continuously or jump to the desired location.