# Article Table of Content in the sidebar

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I need to find an extension to generate the Article Table of Content or Outline in the sidebar [like this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#top_of_page) (right sidebar). The page will scroll to that heading/content when click to the sidebar content.
I found the similar question in [this post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21059/article-table-of-content-as-a-sticky-navigation#_=_) but all the answers are out of date.

Comment: I'n end up with Quick Index of RegularLabs

Comment: Thank you. Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm end up with Quick Index of RegularLabs. It also has the Auto Index feature which auto generate the index for all selected articles.

Comment: Done, @mickmackusa